# Inner join from 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

Having difficulty with inner joins when trying to display from 3 tables. They are structured as in the picture below:

http://pbrd.co/1odLBZy

What I'm trying to achieve is to select the following from the **task** table:

- ProjectID (as project.Name)
- WorkerID (as user.Username)
- Name
- OrderInProject
- TimeSpent
- Description
- DueDate

How would the SQL query be structured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.Name AS ProjectID, u.Username AS WorkerID, t.Name, t.OrderInProject,
       t.TimeSpent, t.Description, t.DueDate
FROM task t
INNER JOIN user u ON t.WorkerID = u.UserID
INNER JOIN project p ON t.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
```

If you also want to get the `Username` of the `ProjectManagerID` then use the following:

```
SELECT p.Name AS ProjectID, u.Username AS WorkerID, t.Name, t.OrderInProject,
       t.TimeSpent, t.Description, t.DueDate, u2.Username AS ProjectManager
FROM task t
INNER JOIN user u ON t.WorkerID = u.UserID
INNER JOIN project p ON t.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
INNER JOIN user u2 ON p.ProjectManagerID = u2.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Visual Studio query builder was producing something different.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer something like this it is best to start with a single table then add the columns and other tables testing each addition along the way. That said the following should be close:

```
SELECT t.Name,
       t.OrderInProject,
       t.TimeSpent,
       t.Description,
       t.DueDate,
       p.Name,
       u.Username
  FROM task t
       INNER JOIN project p ON p.ProjectID = t.ProjectID
       INNER JOIN user u ON u.UserId = t.WorkerID
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Name
    , t.OrderInProject
    , t.TimeSpent
    , t.Description
    , t.DueDate
    , u.Username
    , p.Name
FROM task t
INNER JOIN project p
    on t.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
INNER JOIN user u
    on t.WorkerId = u.UserId
```